# Search a list of values in a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a list of lists as follows.

```
[[0, 0.1, 0.3], [0.5, 0.2, 0.8]]
```

I also have a csv file as follows.

```
No, heading1, heading2, heading3
0, 0, 0.7, 0.3
1, 0, 0.1, 0.3
```

Now I want to search these list of values only using the values in 'heading1', 'heading2' and 'heading3' and if matched return the 'No' corresponding to it.

Can we do this using pandas?

Comment: Do you have some code, what you try? I think you get downvoted because no code (but question is interesting)

Comment: I think the best is remove question and create new with your code (maybe if get some error post it too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by all columns:

```
L = [[0, 0.1, 0.3], [0.5, 0.2, 0.8]]

#helper df with same columns without first
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns= df.columns[1:])
print (df1)
   heading1  heading2  heading3
0       0.0       0.1       0.3
1       0.5       0.2       0.8

#after merge select column No
d = pd.merge(df, df1)['No']
print (d)
0    1
Name: No, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I do not understand the output you get. 0    1
Name: No, dtype: int64. What does this mean?

Comment: Because you want `No` values of matched rows - so here `No` is `1`

Comment: Many thanks. It works. Just wondering why this part is also getting printed "Name: No, dtype: int64"

Comment: Because it is Series. Try check `print (pd.Series([4,8], name='a'))` - each column in df is Series.